# Control-M: Utility to export forecast in textfile?

Tags: forecasting, utility, control-m

I'm looking for a possibility to export a forecast of all jobs of a day into a file (text, csv, xml,..)

Does anybody know if there is such an utility? 
We're currently using Control-M in Version 7.0 on Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a utility called forecastcli which you will find in the filesystem of your Control-M/EM Server installation and the EM Client on your client workstation. I assume you need the Control-M Forecast add-on which requires an extra license as far as I know.

The utility lets you filter jobs of a specific table, datacenter, etc. and you may specify the odate you want to get the forecast for.

Example:
C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Control-M EM 7.0.00\Default\bin\forecastcli.exe -u username -p password -s myEMServer -dc_name datacenterName -table_name MY_CTM_TABLE -odate +1 -job_info_file c:\temp\forecast_out.csv

This command will write all jobs from table MY_CTM_TABLE that run tomorrow (odate +1) into the forecast_out.csv

Hope it helps
Cheers, Werner